# Detecting Click Event of iPhone Call alert in Browsers

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, browser

Is there a way to accomplish this? i.e. I have a page where i pop open a number to place a call on page load using `window.location = 'tel:5555555555';` Although, I'd just like to know when they click **cancel** as opposed to the **call** button. Any ideas on how this could be achieved is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use specific phone api (android, windows phone, etc) to achieve this. I't cannot be done trustfully with javascript.

Comment: Well any ideas how one would accomplish such a task? When you say phone api are you meaning that I could only capture that event in native application code? That seems preposterous (though it also wouldn't surprise me) Still, I feel like there should be some method for catching this event in JS.

Comment: It sure is preposterous. My suggestion to achieve a similar result is to create a popup before changing the location with call and cancel buttons (http://jsfiddle.net/A7RyJ/)

Comment: Yeah that idea came to mind. Not sufficient for my task at hand though. Thanks for all your input. Reckon I'll just let that event slip through the cracks... :P